# Misaligned Dropdown Menu with Hamburger Icon in a Flexbox Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a responsive navigation bar using HTML, CSS, and vanilla JavaScript. The navbar includes a hamburger icon that, when clicked, toggles the visibility of a dropdown menu. However, I'm facing an issue where the dropdown menu items are not aligning correctly right to the hamburger icon.

Here's the code to have a better idea of the problem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Taskboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styling/home.css">
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #333;
            color: white;
        }
        
        header {
            background-color: #222;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        nav {
            position: relative; /* Ensure nav is positioned for absolute positioning of children */
        }
        
        nav h1 {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: blue; /* Set the background color to blue */
            padding: 10px; /* Adjust padding as needed */
            position: relative; /* Ensure relative positioning for the nav h1 */
        }
        
        nav .hamburger {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            color: white; /* Change the color of the hamburger icon to white for better visibility */
        }
        
        .menu {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0; /* Align with the top of nav h1 */
            left: 100%; /* Position to the right of the nav h1 */
            transform: scaleX(0); /* Initially collapsed along the X axis */
            transform-origin: left;
            transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out; /* Animate the transform property */
            background-color: #222;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); /* Optional: Add a shadow for better visibility */
        }
        
        .showNavMenu {
            transform: scaleX(1); /* Expand to full width */
        }
        
        ul li {
            display: block; /* Change to block for vertical list */
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: blue;
            margin-top: -13px;
            margin-left: 8px;
        }
        
        ul li:hover {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .button-blue {
            background: #007bff; /* Assuming a solid blue; replace with gradient if needed */
            color: white;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 4px; /* Adjust as needed */
            margin-left: 10px; /* Space between buttons */
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition for hover effect */
            text-transform: uppercase; /* If the text should be uppercase as in the screenshot */
        }

        nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between; /* Adjust this to align the nav items as in the screenshot */
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px; /* Adjust as needed */
        }
        
        /* Style for the hamburger icon */
        nav .hamburger {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: white; /* Change the color of the hamburger icon to white for better visibility */
        }
        
        /* You might also want to style the <ul> element to have padding and margin 0 */
        nav ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex; /* To align the buttons horizontally */
        }
        
        /* Style for the <li> elements to remove list styles and margins */
        nav ul li {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
        }

        ul li button.button-blue:hover {
            background-color: blue; /* Keep the background color blue on hover */
        }


        .button-blue:hover {
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #0056b3, #004291); /* Darker shade for hover effect */
            box-shadow: 0 2px #002b5e; /* Smaller shadow for pressed effect */
            transform: translateY(2px); /* Gives the button a 'pressed' effect on hover */
        }

        #new-taskboard-form {
            display: none;
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form input[type="text"],
        #new-taskboard-form input[type="file"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form button {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form input[type="text"]::placeholder {
            color: #888;
        }

        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
        
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: 5% auto; /* 5% from the top and centered */
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
            border-radius: 8px; /* Optional: Rounded corners */
        }
        
        .close-button {
            color: #aaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        .close-button:hover,
        .close-button:focus {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .taskboard-selector {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #222;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between; /* Aligns items on opposite ends */
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        #settings-button {
            margin-right: 20px; /* Add some margin for spacing */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>My New Taskboard <span class="hamburger">&#9776;</span></h1>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><button id="update-button" class="button-blue">Update</button></li>
                <li><button id="edit-button" class="button-blue">Edit</button></li>
                <li><button id="open-button" class="button-blue">Open</button></li>
                <li><button id="new-button" class="button-blue">New</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <button id="settings-button" class="button-blue">Settings</button> <!-- Moved outside of the nav, into the header -->
    </header>
    <main>

        <section class="taskboard-grid" id="taskboard-grid">
            <!-- Task cards will be dynamically added here -->
        </section>

        <!-- Hidden form for creating a new taskboard -->
        <div id="new-taskboard-form">
            <input type="text" id="new-taskboard-name" placeholder="Enter Taskboard Name">
            <input type="file" id="new-taskboard-file" accept=".xlsx">
            <button id="submit-new-taskboard">Create Taskboard</button>
        </div>        
    </main>

    <div id="taskboard-selection-modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
            <h2>Select a Taskboard</h2>
            <select id="taskboard-selector" class="taskboard-selector">
                <!-- Taskboard options will be dynamically populated here -->
            </select>
            <button id="select-taskboard-button" class="button-blue">Open Taskboard</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Toggle menu visibility
        const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
        const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
            menu.classList.toggle('showNavMenu');
        });
    
        // Open settings page
        document.getElementById('settings-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.location.href = 'settings';
        });
    
        // Global variable to keep track of the currently selected taskboard
        let currentTaskboard = null;
    
        // Update taskboard functionality
        document.getElementById('update-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!currentTaskboard) {
                alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
                return;
            }
    
            var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
            fileInput.type = 'file';
            fileInput.accept = '.xlsx';
    
            fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                var file = event.target.files[0];
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', file);
                formData.append('name', currentTaskboard);
    
                fetch('/upload/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    fetchTaskboardData(currentTaskboard);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
            });
    
            fileInput.click();
        });
    
        // Open taskboard selection modal
        document.getElementById('open-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            fetch('/list/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(taskboards => {
                populateTaskboardSelector(Object.values(taskboards));
                showModal();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching taskboards:', error);
            });
        });
    
        // Populate taskboard selector in modal
        function populateTaskboardSelector(taskboards) {
            var selector = document.getElementById('taskboard-selector');
            selector.innerHTML = '';
            taskboards.forEach(taskboard => {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = taskboard;
                option.textContent = taskboard;
                selector.appendChild(option);
            });
        }
    
        // Show modal
        function showModal() {
            var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
            modal.style.display = 'block';
        }
    
        // Close modal functionality
        document.querySelector('.close-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        });
    
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    
        // Handle taskboard selection from modal
        document.getElementById('select-taskboard-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var selectedTaskboard = document.getElementById('taskboard-selector').value;
            if (selectedTaskboard) {
                openTaskboard(selectedTaskboard);
                var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
                modal.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                alert('Please select a taskboard.');
            }
        });
    
        // Edit taskboard functionality
        document.getElementById('edit-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!currentTaskboard) {
                alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
                return;
            }
            window.location.href = `/edit?name=${encodeURIComponent(currentTaskboard)}`;
        });
    
        // New taskboard functionality
        document.getElementById('new-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'block';
        });
    
        // Submit new taskboard
        document.getElementById('submit-new-taskboard').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var taskboardName = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value;
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-file');
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
    
            if (!taskboardName || !file) {
                alert('Please enter a taskboard name and select a file.');
                return;
            }
    
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', taskboardName);
            formData.append('file', file);
    
            fetch('/create', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Taskboard created:', data);
                document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value = '';
                fileInput.value = '';
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });
    
        // Function to fetch and display taskboard data
        function fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName) {
            console.log('Fetching data for:', taskboardName); // Debug log
            fetch(`/get/?name=${encodeURIComponent(taskboardName)}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Data received:', data); // Debug log
                var taskboardGrid = document.getElementById('taskboard-grid');
                taskboardGrid.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content
        
                // Check if data is an object and not an array
                if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null && !Array.isArray(data)) {
                    Object.values(data).forEach(createCard); // Iterate over object values
                } else {
                    console.error('Unexpected data format:', data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching taskboard data:', error);
            });
        }
    
        // Function to create a card for each task
        function createCard(row) {
            console.log('Creating card for:', row); // Debug log
            var card = document.createElement('div');
            card.className = 'task-card';
    
            Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
                if (row[key] !== null && row[key] !== undefined) {
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.textContent = `${key}: ${row[key]}`;
                    card.appendChild(p);
                }
            });
    
            document.getElementById('taskboard-grid').appendChild(card); // Append card to taskboard grid
        }
    
        // Open taskboard function
        function openTaskboard(taskboardName) {
            currentTaskboard = taskboardName;
            fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName);
        }
    
        // DOMContentLoaded event listener
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const taskboardName = urlParams.get('name');
            if (taskboardName) {
                openTaskboard(taskboardName);
            }
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an image showing the problem:

[image]

And here is an image how it should look like:

[image]

Could someone help me understand why the dropdown menu is not aligning correctly right the hamburger icon and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```css
ul li {
  ...
  padding: 7px 5px;
  ...
}

.menu{
 ....
 top: 10px;
 ....
}
```

1. tag li `top: 10px;` is beacuse you assign `padding: 10px 20px;` to header.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working! :)

Comment: Actually, I think I fixed it myself!

Comment: Could you share the code, So it will be help ful for others dev and also here is the [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/al_faiz_ahmed/jcu3d794/1/) to actaully see what is happening.

Comment: Yes, I answered my question and published the whole code fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing the whole code fixed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Taskboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styling/home.css">
    <style>
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #333;
            color: white;
        }
        
        header {
            background-color: #222;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        nav {
            position: relative; /* Ensure nav is positioned for absolute positioning of children */
        }
        
        nav h1 {
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            background: #007bff; /* Set the background color to blue */
            position: relative; /* Ensure relative positioning for the nav h1 */
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            transform: skewX(-20deg);
        }
        
        nav .hamburger {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            color: white; /* Change the color of the hamburger icon to white for better visibility */
        }
        
        .menu {
            list-style: none;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            left: 100%; /* Position to the right of the nav h1 */
            transform: scaleX(0); /* Initially collapsed along the X axis */
            transform-origin: left;
            transition: transform 350ms ease-in-out; /* Animate the transform property */
            background-color: #222;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); /* Optional: Add a shadow for better visibility */
        }
        
        .showNavMenu {
            transform: scaleX(1); /* Expand to full width */
        }
        
        ul li {
            display: block; /* Change to block for vertical list */
            padding: 5px;
          
            
        }
        
        .button-blue {
            background: #007bff; /* Assuming a solid blue; replace with gradient if needed */
            color: white;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            border-radius: 4px; /* Adjust as needed */
            margin-left: 10px; /* Space between buttons */
            transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition for hover effect */
            text-transform: uppercase; /* If the text should be uppercase as in the screenshot */
            transform: skewX(-20deg);
        }

        nav {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between; /* Adjust this to align the nav items as in the screenshot */
            align-items: center;
            padding: 10px; /* Adjust as needed */
        }
        
        /* Style for the hamburger icon */
        nav .hamburger {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: white; /* Change the color of the hamburger icon to white for better visibility */
        }
        
        /* You might also want to style the <ul> element to have padding and margin 0 */
        nav ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex; /* To align the buttons horizontally */
        }
        
        /* Style for the <li> elements to remove list styles and margins */
        nav ul li {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
        }

        ul li button.button-blue:hover {
            background-color: blue; /* Keep the background color blue on hover */
        }


        .button-blue:hover {
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #0056b3, #004291);
            box-shadow: 0 2px #002b5e;
            transform: translateY(2px) skewX(-20deg); /* Add skew transformation here as well */
        }

        #new-taskboard-form {
            display: none;
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-radius: 8px;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form input[type="text"],
        #new-taskboard-form input[type="file"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form button {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form button:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }

        #new-taskboard-form input[type="text"]::placeholder {
            color: #888;
        }

        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
        
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: 5% auto; /* 5% from the top and centered */
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
            border-radius: 8px; /* Optional: Rounded corners */
        }
        
        .close-button {
            color: #aaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        
        .close-button:hover,
        .close-button:focus {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .taskboard-selector {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        header {
            background-color: #222;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between; /* Aligns items on opposite ends */
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        #settings-button {
            margin-right: 20px; /* Add some margin for spacing */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>My New Taskboard <span class="hamburger">&#9776;</span></h1>
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><button id="update-button" class="button-blue">Update</button></li>
                <li><button id="edit-button" class="button-blue">Edit</button></li>
                <li><button id="open-button" class="button-blue">Open</button></li>
                <li><button id="new-button" class="button-blue">New</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <button id="settings-button" class="button-blue">Settings</button> <!-- Moved outside of the nav, into the header -->
    </header>
    <main>

        <section class="taskboard-grid" id="taskboard-grid">
            <!-- Task cards will be dynamically added here -->
        </section>

        <!-- Hidden form for creating a new taskboard -->
        <div id="new-taskboard-form">
            <input type="text" id="new-taskboard-name" placeholder="Enter Taskboard Name">
            <input type="file" id="new-taskboard-file" accept=".xlsx">
            <button id="submit-new-taskboard">Create Taskboard</button>
        </div>        
    </main>

    <div id="taskboard-selection-modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
            <h2>Select a Taskboard</h2>
            <select id="taskboard-selector" class="taskboard-selector">
                <!-- Taskboard options will be dynamically populated here -->
            </select>
            <button id="select-taskboard-button" class="button-blue">Open Taskboard</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Toggle menu visibility
        const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
        const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
        hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
            menu.classList.toggle('showNavMenu');
        });
    
        // Open settings page
        document.getElementById('settings-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            window.location.href = 'settings';
        });
    
        // Global variable to keep track of the currently selected taskboard
        let currentTaskboard = null;
    
        // Update taskboard functionality
        document.getElementById('update-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!currentTaskboard) {
                alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
                return;
            }
    
            var fileInput = document.createElement('input');
            fileInput.type = 'file';
            fileInput.accept = '.xlsx';
    
            fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
                var file = event.target.files[0];
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file', file);
                formData.append('name', currentTaskboard);
    
                fetch('/upload/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    fetchTaskboardData(currentTaskboard);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
            });
    
            fileInput.click();
        });
    
        // Open taskboard selection modal
        document.getElementById('open-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            fetch('/list/')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(taskboards => {
                populateTaskboardSelector(Object.values(taskboards));
                showModal();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching taskboards:', error);
            });
        });
    
        // Populate taskboard selector in modal
        function populateTaskboardSelector(taskboards) {
            var selector = document.getElementById('taskboard-selector');
            selector.innerHTML = '';
            taskboards.forEach(taskboard => {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = taskboard;
                option.textContent = taskboard;
                selector.appendChild(option);
            });
        }
    
        // Show modal
        function showModal() {
            var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
            modal.style.display = 'block';
        }
    
        // Close modal functionality
        document.querySelector('.close-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        });
    
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    
        // Handle taskboard selection from modal
        document.getElementById('select-taskboard-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var selectedTaskboard = document.getElementById('taskboard-selector').value;
            if (selectedTaskboard) {
                openTaskboard(selectedTaskboard);
                var modal = document.getElementById('taskboard-selection-modal');
                modal.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                alert('Please select a taskboard.');
            }
        });
    
        // Edit taskboard functionality
        document.getElementById('edit-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!currentTaskboard) {
                alert('Please select a taskboard first.');
                return;
            }
            window.location.href = `/edit?name=${encodeURIComponent(currentTaskboard)}`;
        });
    
        // New taskboard functionality
        document.getElementById('new-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'block';
        });
    
        // Submit new taskboard
        document.getElementById('submit-new-taskboard').addEventListener('click', function() {
            var taskboardName = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value;
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('new-taskboard-file');
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
    
            if (!taskboardName || !file) {
                alert('Please enter a taskboard name and select a file.');
                return;
            }
    
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', taskboardName);
            formData.append('file', file);
    
            fetch('/create', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Taskboard created:', data);
                document.getElementById('new-taskboard-form').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('new-taskboard-name').value = '';
                fileInput.value = '';
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });
    
        // Function to fetch and display taskboard data
        function fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName) {
            console.log('Fetching data for:', taskboardName); // Debug log
            fetch(`/get/?name=${encodeURIComponent(taskboardName)}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Data received:', data); // Debug log
                var taskboardGrid = document.getElementById('taskboard-grid');
                taskboardGrid.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content
        
                // Check if data is an object and not an array
                if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null && !Array.isArray(data)) {
                    Object.values(data).forEach(createCard); // Iterate over object values
                } else {
                    console.error('Unexpected data format:', data);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching taskboard data:', error);
            });
        }
    
        // Function to create a card for each task
        function createCard(row) {
            console.log('Creating card for:', row); // Debug log
            var card = document.createElement('div');
            card.className = 'task-card';
    
            Object.keys(row).forEach(key => {
                if (row[key] !== null && row[key] !== undefined) {
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    p.textContent = `${key}: ${row[key]}`;
                    card.appendChild(p);
                }
            });
    
            document.getElementById('taskboard-grid').appendChild(card); // Append card to taskboard grid
        }
    
        // Open taskboard function
        function openTaskboard(taskboardName) {
            currentTaskboard = taskboardName;
            fetchTaskboardData(taskboardName);
        }
    
        // DOMContentLoaded event listener
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
            const taskboardName = urlParams.get('name');
            if (taskboardName) {
                openTaskboard(taskboardName);
            }
        });
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be good to explain what you fixed